# Could not find a part of the path in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to build a method which is able to write in a file the number of files in another folder. I already got it but it does not work because gives me an error:

> Could not find a part of the path '
>   C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop...\bin\release\%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local_logC'

This is my code:

```
private static int GetCountGFiles(string dirname)
{
    int fileCount = 0;
    dirname = dirname.TrimEnd(new char[] { '\\' }) + @"\";

    var fixedDirname = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(dirname);

    fileCount += System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fixedDirname).Length;

    string[] all_subdirs = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(dirname);

    foreach (string dir in all_subdirs)
        fileCount += GetCountGFiles(dirname); 

    string data = string.Format("LogReg.txt");

    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filePath);
    var fileandpath = filePath + data;

    using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText(fileandpath))
    {
        writer.WriteLine("[" + DateTime.Now + "]" + " - " + "Nº de Records: (" + fileCount.ToString() + ")");
    }

    return fileCount;
}
```

And then I call the method like this :

```
GetCountGFiles(@"%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Cargas - Amostras\_logsC\");
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Methods like `Directory.GetFiles` and `Directory.GetDirectories` will not automatically figure out what the environment variables that you pass to it are. You need to do that manually with [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx). For example:

```
var fixedDirname = Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables(dirname);
```

Now you can do this:

```
fileCount += System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(fixedDirname).Length;
```

(PS No need to use `ToString()` on a `string`)

Comment: First thank you for the reply. I've edited the post, but it still gives me the error. If I change the path to "C:\\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\_logsC" when I call the method it doesn't gives me the error.

Comment: You need to update all places where `dirname` is used in the method, you still use it in 2 places.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I were able to solve it with that!

Answer (score 2):

That "%USERPROFILE%" part is a placeholder for an environment variable. The file APIs have no idea how to handle that.

You need to use [`Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.expandenvironmentvariables(v=vs.110).aspx) on your input string,
before passing it to `Directory.GetFiles`

Comment: @DavidG Thanks (let me return that ;-)

Comment: You don't use `fixedDirname` everywhere you should, but at a couple of places still the `dirname`, containing the `%USERPROFILE%`. In the comments on his answer, @DavidG already told you as well.